# logrotate w/apache2 log files

Tags: logging, apache-http-server, rotate, logrotate

I have apache setup to generate new log files everyday:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -f /var/log/apache2/access.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M 86400" combined
```

Then I'm trying to use logrotate to zip these files:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log.* {
    compress
    create 0644 root root
    daily
    delaycompress
    missingok
    maxage 7
}
```

What happens is that I get a bunch of files that look like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-21-00_00.1.1.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-21-00_00.2.gz.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-21-00_00.3.gz.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-22-00_00.1.1.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-22-00_00.2.gz.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-22-00_00.3.gz.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-23-00_00.1.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 2011-11-26 06:49 access.log.2011-11-23-00_00.2.gz.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44590255 2011-11-25 18:59 access.log.2011-11-25-00_00.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-23-00_00.1.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-24-00_00.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-21-00_00.1.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-21-00_00.2.gz.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        20 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-22-00_00.1.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        33 2011-11-25 06:42 access.log.2011-11-22-00_00.2.gz.4.gz
```

What I want is to have a new file generated everyday and have the previous days file gzip'd.  How should I setup my logrotate to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log.*
```

matches all files in the /var/log/apache2 directory, so includes all gzipped files already present.  It is basically compressing the files already compressed.

Change it to

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
```

to make sure it only acts on the access.log file.  Other than that, the settings are right.

Comment: The only issue with that is I'm adding a time/date stamp to the filename in the CustomLog line.  So I guess changing the CustomLog line to use access.<datetime_stamp>.log would be better so I could use /access.*.log

Comment: Aah, yes I see.  Yeah, you need to exclude the .gz files somehow.  Changing the timestamp position in the filename would be the simplest way.

Comment: marking this answer more or less correct since updating the filename does the trick.